# Can we determine the presence of carbon by simply heating or charring the substance?

Tags: organic-chemistry

Char is made of Carbon, but just because a substance char, does it immediately mean it contains carbon?

Also,
Why is charring not a good test for detecting carbon in organic compounds?
I searched that because the test can't differentiate an elemental carbon from an organic carbon. Can someone elaborate or give an example?

Comment: Other compounds also char, not just carbon. Also, some carbon compounds won't char. That is why it is is a poor test.

Comment: If you can fix CO2, than definitely your sample contains C in a form or another. For the rest see answer.  If in concomitance with CO2 you see water, this point to organics. By the way, I won't check for carbon in organic compounds. I would rather check if they are organic and flame as well as conc. Sulphuric acid do quite well to this end.

Answer (score 1):

Not all carbon-containing chemical char. For example, sodium carbonate, $\ce{Na2CO3}$ just produces $\ce{CO2}$. Sodium carbonate might be viewed as inorganic, though.

An organic chemical that behaves in a similar way is [hexamethylenetetramine](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hexamethylenetetramine), or hexamine, $\ce{(CH2)6N4}$. On heating, it decomposes primarily into formaldehyde, $\ce{H-CHO}$, and ammonia, $\ce{NH3}$, though [there are traces of other gases](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/2688388) such as $\ce{HCN}$ and $\ce{CO}$. For that reason, hexamine is used as a smokeless fuel (no char left behind, as the saying goes).